# dynamically append data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to build my code as general as possible.

Part of my code is to build couple of data frames (which latter would be joined to one 'master' data frame), however each of this partial data frames contains variable number of columns.

I'm passing to my function a list which contains the name of the columns names. How can I make this as general as possible. If I'll pass to my function any of list1 or list2

```
list1 = ['a.element1', 'a.element2']
list2 = ['b.elementA', 'b.elementB']
```

Eventual df1 shall contain columns  `element1 and element2` and df contain columns `elementA and elementB`

```
df1 = myFunciton(list1, data1)
df2 = myFunciton(list2, data2)
```

Comment: So, your ultimate goal is to make one dataframe that has some (but not all) of `a`'s columns, and some (but not all) of `b`'s columns. Is that correct? (If you just want all of `a` and all of `b`, your lists of column names are unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
df_master= df1.append([df2, df3, .., dfn])
```

Otherwise, please give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you mean and want to achieve.